# How do I find live and pending entries when using an array?

Tags: status, pending, array

I have this in my listings template, but the 'pending' parameter does not seem to work.

```
{% set urlCat = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}
{% set category = craft.categories.slug( urlCat ) %}
{% set allEntries =  craft.entries.status('live, pending').section('sectionName').relatedTo(category).find() %}
```

This seems to only return 'live' entries even though I do have 'pending' specified.  I've tried this several ways and cannot seem to make it work.

The strange thing is that this seems to work fine on my single entry page where I have:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionName').slug(selected).status("live, pending").first() %}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried my answer, pixel? Setting `status` to `null` doesn't return only 'live' and 'pending' entries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all entries regardless of status with `.status(null)`:

```
{% set allEntries =  craft.entries.section('sectionName').relatedTo(category).status(null).find() %}
```

Comment: This will also show all 'disabled' and 'expired' entries though.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set both states in single/double quotes:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.status('live', 'pending').section('sectionName').relatedTo(category).find() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Craft CMS 3:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.status('pending, live').section('sectionName').relatedTo(category).find() %}
```